# How do I block site redirects from injections ads?

Tags: php, java, html, javascript, jquery

I have a site where I have various advertisements from a few advertiser , and from time to time my site is redirected how many other porn sites etc ... 
I installed anti adblock script because I gain from ads!
On my site are not installed link or script redirect or for pop-up .
Is there any way I can block these redirect injections that come from ads from php, java or htaccess?
thanks

Comment: If you advertising partner places unwanted ads I'd suggest moving to a more reputable advertising partner.

Comment: IMO this question is more suitable for [webmasters.se].